# S3 uploading is taking too much time

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

When I try to upload a video file into an S3 bucket it takes so much time to upload that file. But the video file is uploaded that is not an issue. But the uploading time is pretty high however my video file size is just 30MB. So this is not a cool way to upload video files from my application. I have to upload some large video files into S3 bucket that could take around 200MB per video. So I need a better way to upload these video files into an S3 bucket.

Here is my code snippet,

```
        const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
        const fs = require('fs');
        const fileType = require('file-type');
        const bluebird = require('bluebird');
        const multiparty = require('multiparty');
        const cors = require('cors');
        app.use(cors());
        app.options('*', cors());

        // configure the keys for accessing AWS
        AWS.config.update({
          accessKeyId: "xxx",
          secretAccessKey: "yyy"
        });

        // configure AWS to work with promises
        AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(bluebird);

        // create S3 instance
        const s3 = new AWS.S3();

        // abstracts function to upload a file returning a promise
        const uploadFile = (buffer, name, type) => {
          const params = {
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Body: buffer,
            Bucket: "bucket-name",
            ContentType: type.mime,
            Key: `${name}.${type}`
          };
          return s3.upload(params).promise();
        };

        // Define POST route
        app.post('/test-upload', (request, response) => {
          const form = new multiparty.Form();
          response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            form.parse(request, async (error, fields, files) => {
              if (error) throw new Error(error);
              try {
                const path = files.file[0].path;
                const buffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
                const type = fileType(buffer);
                const timestamp = Date.now().toString();
                const fileName = `test/${timestamp}-lg`;
                const data = await uploadile(buffer, fileName, type);
                console.log("Data", data);
                return response.status(200).send(data) +" " + data;
              } catch (error) {
                return response.status(400).send(error);
              }
            });
        });

        app.get('/', function(req, res){
            res.send('Hello!')
        })

        var listener = app.listen(9000);
        console.log('Server up and running...' + listener.address().address);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not a node person, but I wonder whether [Class: AWS.S3.ManagedUpload — AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html) would be suitable?

Comment: Have you verified that the bottleneck is not the network connection of your own client? Have you tried using multipart upload to take advantage of the bandwidth afforded by multiple connections?

Comment: Where are you uploading it from? From within VPC or from your own laptop?

Comment: I tried to upload from my own laptop.